Add flag images in options tag in angular
I want to add flag images to a drop-down list that uses select and option tags in angular
I have tried adding background image method (works in select tag but not in option tag), unicode (not working), emoji (only country code is displayed).
I am still learning angular, please help.
I have tried adding background image method (works in select tag but not in option tag), unicode (not working), emoji (only country code is displayed).
Is there any solution for windows (chrome browser)
<div class="w-288">
   <select class="dc-select" (change)="updateLanguage($event.target.value)">
     <option>English</option>
     <option>French</option>
  </select>
</div>

